# About the labels on OpenCV GrabCut segmentation with mask?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-segmentation

I'm working with OpenCV to segment some images using [GrabCut](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html). On my image I want to segment a single a single object from the background. I want to find the outline of the object; I know it's approximate location so I label the center of it as **FG = Foreground**. Then I label a small band around it as **P_BG = Possible background**, this is the area where I want GrabCut to perform the segmentation. Finally, the rest of the image is labeled as **BG = Background**. I don't want GrabCut to do anything here (no graph, no color model, no anything)

Now, there are 4 possible labels:

- Probable Background (P_BG)
- Probable Foreground (P_FG)
- Background (BG)
- Foreground (FG)

The question(s)

- **What's the actual difference between `P_BG` and `P_FG`?** (seems obvious but I have used them interchangeably and it changes nothing?
- **What labels does GrabCut use to generate the color models used (probable/non probable)?**
- **Finally, How can I tell GrabCut not to do NOTHING on the Background area?** (I want it to ignore the background area totally, its evidently doing something there since segmenting the full image takes much longer than segmenting a cropped version (see the image below), I cant afford to wait for it to analyze the whole image, I'm already providing the region where it should "work")

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It couldn't do nothing on the BG because it uses such pixels as models of 100% sure background. The same is for FG pixels.

You will see the difference between P_FG and P_BG if you would not use FG and BG labels. This P_* labels are used for first model, but can be relabeled in the next iterations.

Actually, initialization with rectangle is the same as using mask with P_FG inside rectangle and P_BG for the rest pixels.

Answer (score 1):

In the current implementation of GrabCut in OpenCV there is no way to have GrabCut completely ignore any pixel.  Every pixel is used in the creation of the foreground and background color models.

If the region you want to have not be ignored is rectangular, you can use roi to first extract the relevant region of the image, and then call GrabCut on the remainder.  This will cause the pixels outside the original ROI to not be used in the color model, and will be an efficient implementation since nothing is copied.